# Formula for the summation of $2^i$ where $i$ has bounds $[0, n)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, formal-proofs

Having difficulty approaching this problem; I want to remove the summation symbol to give a pure algebraic formula in terms of $n$. Any guidance? I want to develop my proof/derivation toolbox more too, so any guidance in general when approaching problems like this would be very useful!

$$\tag 4 \sum_{i=0}^n 2^i$$

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula and then please update your question if you need any clarifications; if not, the Wikipedia article is pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: Why did you give the formula a numbering of $(4)$?

Comment: accident, sorry about that, I'm new to the math typescript so I was copying syntax from elsewhere. Thanks for the help!